# Download a file generated by "pdfmake" with a graphQL query

Tags: node.js, graphql, pdfmake

How can I make a query in graphQL that can download a pdf using "pdfmake"

```
@Resolver()
export class PdfResolver {
@Authorized()
@Query(() => String)
async CretePdf() {
 const fs = require("fs");
 const Pdfmake = require("pdfmake");

 var fonts = {
   Roboto: {
     normal: "fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf",
     bold: "fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf",
     italics: "fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf",
     bolditalics: "fonts/roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf",
   },
 };

 let pdfmake = new Pdfmake(fonts);

 let docDefination = {
   content: ["Hello World!"],
 };

 let pdfDoc;

 pdfDoc = pdfmake.createPdfKitDocument(docDefination, {});
 pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("pdfs/test.pdf"));
 pdfDoc.end();

return "Pdf created successfully";
}
```

This query creates a pdf within my project.
What I need is that instead, when this query is called the pdf is downloaded.
I have seen that in the documentation there is a method called download, but it is for the frontend and I don't know if I can use it

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your file somewhere temporarily (ex: S3 if you're on AWS)
2. send the URI of this file to the client in the graphql response data
3. have the client download from the provided URI
4. You can then either send another mutation to the server to remove the successfully downloaded file or let it expire after some timeout.

Comment: Do you know a library to create the temporary file in nodejs? or an easy way to do the whole process in node? I could not do it

Comment: See for example https://pipedream.com/docs/code/nodejs/working-with-files/